# Generating stubs in ./src instead of root directory using Axis and Ant

Tags: ant, axis

How do I get this Ant file to generate my stubs in the ./src directory instead of the root directory for the target "generate-service-stub"?

My directory structure looks like this:

- My Project/

  - build.xml
  - src/

The namespace defined in my WSDL is "http://www.example.org/SimpleService/".  So after the build, the directory structure looks like this:

```
- My Project/
  - build.xml
  - src/
  - org/ <-- notice how this falls outside of the src/ directory
    - example
      - www
        - SimpleService
          - *.java
          - *.wsdd
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
- My Project/
  - build.xml
  - src/
    - org/ <-- notice how this falls within the src/ directory
      - example
        - www
          - SimpleService
            - *.java
            - *.wsdd
```

Here's my build.xml file:

```
<project name="SimpleService">
    <property name="axis.home" value="C:/axis-1_4" />
    <property name="javamail.home" value="C:/javamail-1.4.4" />
    <property name="jsf.home" value="C:/jaf-1.1" />
    <path id="axis.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${axis.home}/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${javamail.home}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${jsf.home}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="axis-tasks.properties" classpathref="axis.classpath" />
    <target name="generate-service-stub">
        <axis-wsdl2java serverside="true" url="SimpleService.wsdl">
        </axis-wsdl2java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Or is the way it's working actually preferred, so that I don't inadvertently overwrite my *SOAPImpl.java file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`axis-wsdl2java` Ant task](http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/ant/axis-wsdl2java.html) has an attribute `output` to control the destination.  So it should be something like:

```
<axis-wsdl2java serverside="true" url="SimpleService.wsdl" output="src" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  As you can tell I'm new to Ant and Axis.  Thanks for pointing me to the docs.  That helps.